# How to achieve sort by value in spark java

Tags: java, sorting, apache-spark

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Float> counts = ones
            .reduceByKey(new Function2<Float, Float, Float>() {
                @Override
                public Float call(Float i1, Float i2) {
                    return i1 + i2;
                }
            });
```

My output looks like this:

```
id,value
100002,23.47
100003,42.78
200003,50.45
190001,30.23
```

I would like the output to be sorted by value like:

```
200003,50.45
100003,42.78
190001,30.23
100002,23.47
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Spark does `operations` on Keys. If you need to sort on `values` and it is good to be a Key(?), then map the RDD accordingly and use [sortByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#sortByKey%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 4):

Scala has a nice `sortBy` method. Could not find the Java equivalent, but this is the scala implementation:

```
  def sortBy[K](
      f: (T) => K,
      ascending: Boolean = true,
      numPartitions: Int = this.partitions.size)
      (implicit ord: Ordering[K], ctag: ClassTag[K]): RDD[T] =
    this.keyBy[K](f)
        .sortByKey(ascending, numPartitions)
        .values
```

So, basically similar to the above, but it add a key instead of swapping forward and backwards. I use it like this: `.sortBy(_._2)` (sort by picking the second element of the tuple).

Comment: There is a `sortBy`, but it's defined on `JavaRDD`, not `JavaPairRDD`.

Comment: Converting to `JavaRDD` is as simple as `counts.map(t -> t)`, rest is the similar to `counts.map(t -> t).sortBy(t -> t._2, false, counts.getNumPartitions())`

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no specific API to sort the data on value.

May be you need to do below steps:

1) Swap key and value 
2) Use sortByKey API 
3) Swap key and value

Look at the more details about sortByKey in beloe reference: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#sortByKey%28boolean%29

for swap, we can use Scala Tuple API:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2

For example, I have Java Pair RDD from the below function.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = ones.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
          @Override
          public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
            return i1 + i2;
          }
  });
```

Now, To swap key and value, you can use below code:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> swappedPair = counts.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Integer, String>() {
           @Override
           public Tuple2<Integer, String> call(Tuple2<String, Integer> item) throws Exception {
               return item.swap();
           }

        });
```

Hope this helps. You need to take care of the data types.

Comment: will spark java supports the scala swap function?

Comment: Yes. You can use scala.Tuple2.swap() API in Java.

Comment: I have tried but i am not getting... will u please provide code on how to use swap

Comment: please share how to sort after swapping it.

Comment: Hi Ramana, Thanks for your update....it worked... and please share me code for how to sort in descending order....

Comment: Please have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56641/producing-a-sorted-wordcount-with-spark